# iMac OSX Lion upgrade - Photo Booth stopped working

Tags: osx-lion, imac

After I upgraded my [2009] iMac to OSX Lion (a few days ago), the Photo Booth program stopped working. When I click on the icon, all I get is the following error message:

**Photo Booth cannot be opened because of a problem**

With the following stack trace:

```
Process:         Photo Booth [1367]
Path:            /Users/USER/Desktop/*/Photo Booth.app/Contents/MacOS/Photo Booth
Identifier:      com.apple.PhotoBooth
Version:         3.0.1 (117)
Build Info:      PhotoBooth-1170000~3
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [149]

Date/Time:       2011-07-27 20:48:00.458 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7 (11A511)
Report Version:  9
Sleep/Wake UUID: BA40DCC4-26BB-480D-9590-709AA598D4CF

Interval Since Last Report:          187610 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           10
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   7
Anonymous UUID:                      9994E544-979E-4577-9413-0D163B53E3B9

Crashed Thread:  0

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _kFigTimeInvalid
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Desktop/*/Photo Booth.app/Contents/MacOS/Photo Booth
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/Versions/A/CoreMedia
 in /Users/USER/Desktop/*/Photo Booth.app/Contents/MacOS/Photo Booth
```

**PS:** I also installed OSX Lion on my MacBook Air and had no issues.

Comment: Could it be that Photo Booth expects to be in your `/Applications` folder? From here it seems like it's on your Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework` folder over from your other Mac. If this doesn't work, try moving Photo Booth back into your /Applications folder, or reinstalling Lion.